# How to install virtualenv on Centos6?

Tags: python, flask, pip, virtualenv, centos6

I want to apply my Flask project on my workplace Centos6. So I followed guide from google to install pip, virtualenv, and flask, but I cannot successfully install either pip or virtualenv.

What I have done is this:

1) http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/05/30/install-pip-centos-rhel-ubuntu-debian/

```
#rpm -ivh httplink://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

#yum install -y python-pip
(version 7.1.0-1.el6)

#pip install virtualenv
```

this gives

> urllib3 will issue (InsecurePlatformWarning)

2) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4

```
#curl httplink://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python2.7 -
```

this gives

> curl: (77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

3) http://www.ylabs.co.kr/index.php?document_srl=31854&mid=board_dev_python&order_type=asc&sort_index=title

with python2.7

```
#cd /tmp

#wget --no-check-certificate httplink://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-1.4.2.tar.gz

#tar -xvf setuptools-1.4.2.tar.gz

#cd setuptools-1.4.2

#python2.7 setup.py install
```

This gives

```
Searching for pip
Reading httplink://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on httplink://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [Errno 0] _ssl.c:343: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading httplink://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on httplink://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 0] _ssl.c:343: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

4) http://novafactory.net/archives/3074

```
# wget httplink://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py

# python3.4 ez_setup.py

# easy_install-3.4 pip

# pip3.4 install virtualenv
```

This gives

```
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Cannot fetch index base URL httplink://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement virtualenv
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for virtualenv
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

My system is CentOS release 6.8 (Final), python 2.6/2.7/3.4

```
pip3 -V : 
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)

pip2 -V :
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
```

Comment: Is `httplink` a valid protocol? You should download get-pip.py from here: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py - i.e. `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && sudo python get-pip.py`

Comment: It seems that the SSL on your platform is very broken

Comment: I guess the `httplink://` is some kind of copypaste error?

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for the advices

what I have done is to not use pip, instead I just download python module packages.

I went to the link http://pypi.python.org/simple/
which I got from error message from above (my 3 trial)

and download [package] what I looked for

and tar -xvf [package]

cd [package]

[python setup install]

So I could install Flask and virtualenv without using pip